# Prevent double outputs from python logging library

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Right. I'm running a reasonably complicated (for me) object based model, and I'm looking to get my outputs in order. Previously I've just used `print()` to dump outputs into the console, and attached `if` functions to them if I want to switch different ones on and off. While this works fine on basic code, I'm getting a bit un-glued on this project (which is an order of magnitude bigger than things I've attempted before). I understand that the python logging library allows me to do this much more tidily and output to a logfile etc.

As it stands, the code runs this function on running, which sets up everything the way I want it (I think). I've set it up inside the model, as I am going to be conducting ensemble runs, and I'd like to rename the logfile each time for a new run.

```
def set_logger(file_name):
    '''sets up output via loggers and a output file.'''
    output = ('%(asctime)-20s %(filename)-15s %(funcName)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format=output,
                        filename=file_name,
                        filemode='w')
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
    return
```

This code outputs everything from the `DEBUG` level and up to a logfile, while displaying `INFO` and up to the console.

My problem is that the the logger appears to stay active when execution finishes, so I end up with  double lines of console output (though not in the logfile) the first time I run it, and triple lines the next time and so on... I assume that  this has something to do with this line: `logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)`, because I am adding a new handler each time I run the code.

Is there an established way to avoid this? I'd like to be able to run the code as normal and have it detect whether there is an existing instance of `console` and just not replicate it if there is, but the docs are pretty difficult to understand on this one, and it's got me stumped.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if your RootLogger (`logging.getLogger('')`) has the handler:

```
def set_logger(file_name):
    '''sets up output via loggers and a output file.'''
    output = ('%(asctime)-20s %(filename)-15s %(funcName)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format=output,
                        filename=file_name,
                        filemode='w')
    root_logger = logging.getLogger('')
    if len(root_logger.handlers) > 0: # verifies if it has already a handler
        console = logging.StreamHandler()
        console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
        console.setFormatter(formatter)
        root_logger.addHandler(console)
```

However, if in the future you have more than one handler, and you want to check if one specific handler is in your logger, you can name your handlers to be more precise:

```
def set_logger(file_name):
    '''sets up output via loggers and a output file.'''
    output = ('%(asctime)-20s %(filename)-15s %(funcName)-15s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format=output,
                        filename=file_name,
                        filemode='w')
    root_logger = logging.getLogger('')
    # Verify if there is already a handler named "console"
    if any((handler.name == "console" for handler in root_logger.handlers)):
        console = logging.StreamHandler()
        console.name = "console"
        console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
        console.setFormatter(formatter)
    root_logger.addHandler(console)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, as soon as I posted the question, came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47924371/4741979), which while kind of quick and dirty, does do the trick. Adding this code at the beginning, wipes the list of handlers and we just add a new one every time. Less elegant than [eqperes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414781/4741979) but it does do the job...

```
root_logger.handlers = []
```